# SVG image not displaying in any version of IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm not convinced that it's the old "SVG external reference not loading in IE" problem. Reason for that there are other SVG images loading correctly.

To see the issue, please preview this site in IE (http://votensw.info/) at screen width less than 900px. Click on the search button top right.

In other browsers, the button changes to an "X" over a grey background:
[screenshot of close button][2].

In IE, neither the svg "X" image, nor the grey background display correctly.

While there may be the svg problem with IE, I think that there's also some problem with the CSS, but I can't see what might be the problem.

I'd be very grateful to anyone who can inspect the css and find a fix for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon uses svg use

svg use doesn't work in IE if it has to load something from an external resource.

Please check the Browser Compatability in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use).

from the mentioned site:

```
<svg class="icon icon-blue search__icon-close" aria-hidden="true">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.votensw.info/_designs/css/alternative_2017/main_alternative.css/sprite.svg#close"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'd accept this answer, except that the "search" icon also uses this method, and it's showing fine in IE: <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.vote.nsw.gov.au/_designs/css/alternative_2017/main_alternative.css/sprite.svg#search"></use>

Comment: @MichaelAhearn The symbol icon used for search is a simple path. But the close icon uses 'use' for creating the mask. I guess features like that are not supported.

Comment: but the search uses 'use' also, which is why I'm confused about why it is showing, but the close one isn't. I actually played around with the code inside the sprite, and ended up getting the closed 'X' to show in IE - but not all the time - sounds strange, but it only appears sometimes, after a refresh!

Comment: @MichaelAhearn. Yes the search uses 'use' but did you check the source of the 'use'  the symbol had a clippath and use within the symbol. But now it's updated to path 

<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 99.9 100" id="close"><path d="M13.9 0c-.7-.1-1.4.1-1.9.6L.6 12c-1 1-.7 2.8.5 4.1L35 50 1.1 83.9C-.1 85.1-.4 87 .6 88L12 99.3c1 1 2.9.9 4.1-.4L50 65l33.8 34c1.2 1.2 3.1 1.4 4.1.4L99.3 88c1-1 .7-2.8-.5-4.1L64.9 50l33.9-33.9c1.2-1.2 1.5-3.1.5-4.1L87.9.7c-1-1-2.8-.7-4.1.5L49.9 35 16.1 1.2C15.5.5 14.6.1 13.9 0"/></symbol>

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to set the width *and* height for svgs to work in IE.